# How to add a border to column headers and caption to pandas dataframe using .style?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, pandas-styles

I am trying to adding borders to the column headers and also the caption to the dataframe below. I can successfully add a border to the caption, but when I attempt to add a border around the column headers I believe it overrides the caption border and format. Is there a way to add borders to both? I tried adding two .set_table_styles() statements and I also tried incorporating them into the same chunk of code, but I must be misunderstanding how to code is being interpreted when ran.

```
final = unique_shows_imdb_final.style.bar(subset=["Netflix IMDb Score"], color='')\
                     .bar(subset=["Hulu IMDb Score"], color='')\
                     .bar(subset=["Prime IMDb Score"], color='')\
                     .bar(subset=["Disney+ IMDb Score"],color='').background_gradient(cmap=sns.cm.rocket_r,axis=None).hide_index().format(precision=1)

final.set_properties(subset=['Rank'], **{'font-weight': 'bold'})



final.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}
).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': '',
    'props': [('border', '2px black solid !important')]}]
).set_caption("Top 20 TV Shows per Streaming Platform").set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'black'),
        ('font-size', '25px'),
        ('text-align','center'),
        ('border', '3px black solid !important')
    ]
}])
```

[image: Successful border around caption]

final = unique_shows_imdb_final.style.bar(subset=["Netflix IMDb Score"], color='')
.bar(subset=["Hulu IMDb Score"], color='')
.bar(subset=["Prime IMDb Score"], color='')
.bar(subset=["Disney+ IMDb Score"],color='').background_gradient(cmap=sns.cm.rocket_r,axis=None).hide_index().format(precision=1)

```
final.set_properties(subset=['Rank'], **{'font-weight': 'bold'})



final.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}
).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': '',
    'props': [('border', '2px black solid !important')]}]
).set_caption("Top 20 TV Shows per Streaming Platform").set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'black'),
        ('font-size', '25px'),
        ('text-align','center'),
        ('border', '3px black solid !important')
    ]
}])

final.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '10pt'),('border-style','solid'),('border-width','1px')]}])
```

[image: Successful add of border around column header, lose formatting/border of caption]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) by default has `overwrite=True`.

From the Docs:

**overwrite bool, default True**

> Styles are replaced if `True`, or extended if `False`. CSS rules are preserved so most recent styles set will dominate if selectors intersect.
> New in version 1.2.0.

This means that (by default) each call will overwrite the previous styles, we can set `overwrite=False` and also add in the missing "border-color" from the table styles:

```
final.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}
).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': '',
    'props': [('border', '2px black solid !important')]}]
).set_caption("Top 20 TV Shows per Streaming Platform").set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'black'),
        ('font-size', '25px'),
        ('text-align', 'center'),
        ('border', '3px black solid !important')
    ]
}], overwrite=False)  # Don't overwrite previous styles

final.set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'th', 'props': [
        ('font-size', '10pt'),
        ('border-style', 'solid'),
        ('border-width', '1px'),
        ('border-color', 'black') # Missing Border Color here
    ]
}], overwrite=False)  # Don't overwrite previous styles
```

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 6)))
final = df.style
```

Sample Output:

[image: styled table]

---

However, generally it is better practice to style the table last and pass a single list of selector dictionaries:

```
final.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}
).set_caption("Top 20 TV Shows per Streaming Platform").set_table_styles([
    # Selector 1
    {'selector': '',
     'props': [('border', '2px black solid !important')]},
    # Selector 2
    {'selector': 'caption',
     'props': [
         ('color', 'black'),
         ('font-size', '25px'),
         ('text-align', 'center'),
         ('border', '3px black solid !important')]},
    # Selector 3
    {'selector': 'th', 'props': [
        ('font-size', '10pt'),
        ('border-style', 'solid'),
        ('border-width', '1px'),
        ('border-color', 'black')  # Missing Border Color here
    ]}
])
```

This produces the exact same styled frame as above.